# Как выравнивать таблицу по размеру окна?

Tags: html, css, таблицы

У меня проблема с отображением таблицы в браузере.

Так выглядит таблица на большом экране браузера
[image: на большом экране браузера]
Но когда размер экрана уменьшается, происходит следующее:
[image: на маленьком экране браузера]
Как можно это исправить?

Код стиля:

```
<style type="text/css">
   TABLE {
    width: 300px; /* Ширина таблицы */
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
   }
   TD, TH {
    padding: 3px; /* Поля вокруг содержимого таблицы */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Параметры рамки */
   }
   TH {
    background: #b0e0e6; /* Цвет фона */
   }
   {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-fixed-head {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100vh;
}

.table-fixed-head th,
.table-fixed-head td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.333vw;
}

.table-fixed-head thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}

.table-fixed-head thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.table-fixed-head tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.table-fixed-head tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
  </style>
```

Comment: Width: 100%; попробуй ширину таблицы задать вот так

Comment: Ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Пробуй bootstrap, класс ‘container’

Comment: Просто нужно сделать, чтоб таблица в малом окне была такая же, как и на полном экране, чтоб можно было двигать направо, можно добавить горизонтальный бегунок?

Comment: Если задать строго размер то в маленьких экранах скролл само собой появиться

Comment: Добавьте [Минимальный работающий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) своей таблицы со стилями в топик или хотя бы залейте на какой-то сервис и киньте ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отключить overflow при определенных размерах экрана:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.table-fixed-head tbody {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Или попробуйте другие его свойства